# vscode does not jump to definition

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, visual-studio-code

I have a node project that uses ws. VSCode knows about the websocket events and functions but if I add something to prototype then it is recognized in suggestions but I can't jump to definition. It say: ***No definition found for 'setDefaults'***. Is there something I need to configure in VScode to work or am I using it wrong?

[image]

The source to easy copy:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

WebSocket.prototype.setDefaults = function()
{
    console.log("defaults")
}


ws = new WebSocket();

ws.setDefaults()
```

I also tried Find all references, but it does not find the usage of the method.

Comment: I would be interested in what the solution is for this. So far I've been using `Find all references` as a workaround.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your interest, Find all references is not working for me either, see updated post

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: have you added [`JSDoc`](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/inline-documentation-standards/javascript/#functions) headers to your functions in the `ws` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into [this known limitation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10868) around dynamic properties

One workaround: use jsdocs to declare a new type that includes your extension method:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws')

/**
 * @typedef {{ setDefaults: () => void }} WebSocketExtensions
 * @typedef {WebSocket & WebSocketExtensions} ExtendedWebsocket
 * 
 * @type {ExtendedWebsocket}
 */
const ws = new WebSocket();

ws.setDefaults()
```

Comment: Fixed the link.