# Can't jump from JSX to CSS style which was made by material UI on vscode when pressing F12

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, material-ui

I made all of the CSS styles for my React app using Material UI.

When pressing `F12` or `command` + left click in the VSCode editor, I can't jump to the CSS.

[image: screenshot of VSCode editor]

I would expect to jump to the `outer` property of the style object.

the code of style is here:

```
import {
  createStyles,
  createTheme,
  makeStyles,
  Theme,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { CreateCSSProperties } from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";

const theme = createTheme();

export const outer: CreateCSSProperties<{}> = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "row",
};

export const topStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    outer: outer,
  })
);
```

Usually, VSCode is supposed to jump the origin code when pressing `F12` or `command` + left click.

How can I enable that behavior?

Comment: `makeStyles` returns a hook to `topStyles` is not a valid name.  All hooks must start with `use`.  It should be `useTopStyles` or `useStyles`, etc.  I don't know if this is related to the VSCode isssue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `VSCode` extension:

[CSS Peak](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pranaygp.vscode-css-peek)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work

Comment: me neither.....

Answer (score -1):

I believe this issue comes from how you have outer defined as it may be some limitation of vscode (mentioned in link below).

You might have to create a typedef in the document.

See this post for details: [vscode does not jump to definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221018/vscode-does-not-jump-to-definition)

Comment: Thank you for answering! Let me try it.